# xamarin ios Why cant i select a Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, ios-simulator

I am very new to Xamarin, and i have been following the [Hello.ios QuickStart Tutorial](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS/hello,iOS_quickstart/) and the app builds, But i cannot select a simulator for debugging.

My only options in debug are Default or IOS Device. 
I have made my app the starting application and i have the xcode simulator running. I also went into xcode and updated the simulation to 7.1 i think, but i still cannot select a simulation type.

I even tried to go into project-->Active Configuration and tried to select Debug|iphoneSimulator, but it defaults back to just Debug|iPhone

can anyone help me
Thanks

**EDIT**

i am also getting this error : no valid ios code signing keys found in keychain
I dont know if that is caused by my issue in my question.

Comment: if you download the solution form the xamarin site here do you still not get the option for simulator? http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/Hello_iOS

Comment: no valid ios code signing keys is when you are deploying to the device.

Comment: Thanks for that Lain Smith, And ill have a check now and let you know

Comment: Hi there, Alright, downloading their one, i get the Simulaters on in the drop down, did i miss something ?

Comment: the only error i got was that Profiling needs the business edition and up, is that used for the simulators ?

Comment: You dont need the Xamarin Profiler for the simulator that is only if you want to check memory allocation or execution times http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/xamarin-profiler/#Requirements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80268/discussion-between-iain-smith-and-jody-stocks).

Comment: What version of iOS does your project target? In the Info.plist file the iOS version targeted is in the Deployment Target field. Do you have iOS simulators for that version of iOS? I do not see any simulators when creating a new iOS project that targets iOS 8.3, but if I change the deployment target to a lower version, say 8.0, then the simulators are shown in the drop down in the main toolbar.

Comment: How do i check all these things, To be honest, today is my 1st week every using a mac so im still very confused, im a windows man lol, so im not sure how to see what version of mac i have and how to install simulatiors

Comment: To see the iOS simulators - open Xcode, then select Open Developer Tool - iOS Simulator. Then in the iOS simulator select Hardware - Device - Manage Devices. You can install other iOS simulators from Xcode - Preferences - Downloads. Or you can just try using a lower iOS version for your project. By default it uses 8.3.

Answer (score 1):

For the code signing issue, remove the entry in the entitlements textbox under:

iOS project => Project Options => iOS Bundle Signing

See http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39674/iphonesimulator-build-results-in-no-valid-ios-code-signing-keys-found-in-keychain for more information.

An alternative is to configure a signing certificate using an Apple developer account.

Here is a good walkthrough for setting up a certificate.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/